# When do we say safek d'rabanan lekula?

Tags: derabanan, safek, leniencies

There is a concept that in matters of doubt that pertain to derabanans we pasken lekula. I have seen this applied to doubts in realia as well as halachik doubts (eg machlokes). Nevertheless, it is quite obvious that we do *not* say this as a blanket statement at all: halacha, at least from after the Gemara's times, does *not* automatically follow the most meikil rishon, etc.

This is not a modern approach--the Shulchan Aruch/Rema, for example, will often pasken like opinions that are not the most meikil ones. They will often bring multiple opinions down as well, which again implies that we aren't supposed to simply go with the meikil approach.

So: are there any sources that explain how/when to apply safek derabanan lekulah?

Comment: "will often pasken like opinions that are not the most meikil ones" Seemingly those cases aren't a matter of safek so your rule doesn't apply

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Are you understanding that a machlokes rishonim is different than a machlokes acharonim, for example? Or maybe you mean that the Shulchan Aruch is rendering a new psak (ie it is not a safek at all in his mind)? I don't understand how that fits with his famous 2/3 rule re the Rosh, RMBM, and Rif, but interested in hearing!

Comment: Are you asking about בדברי סופרים הלך אחר המיקל? That's a different (although perhaps related) rule. I think it only applies to Chazal, not Rishonim

Comment: There may be a distinct question here, but I think there's too much overlap to leave this open. If you edit your question down to a distinct subset of sorts, flag to reopen

Comment: @robev I'm not familiar with the distinction. Maybe I am misremembering the exact line, but I have definitely seen it brought down for rishonim, acharonim, etc.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.sefaria.org/Shev_Shmat'ta,_Shmatta_1.3.11) one example of a distinction.